# Windows Shell Commands

Tags: php, windows, shell, command, code-injection

I am going to be giving a presentation in class on web site security and I created a demo website (on a VM) with sql injection, xss and PHP injection vulnerabilities.  I am going to load a PHP file that executes shell commands and my question is what is the worst shell command I can do on a Window's PC?  Will "rd /S /Q C:\" delete the C drive successfully?  I am looking to do something that will break the OS.  Thanks!

Comment: The apache user has to have permissions to delete the drive.  Do you really want to do that, though? Won't it ruin your presentation?

Comment: @tandu: He could be running it on a VM.

Comment: @Kaivo true, but deleting the whole hard drive is a little extreme.  You can get the same point across by deleting one file!

Comment: Yeah, I was going to run it on a VM.  I wanted to completely wipe out the computer just for dramatic effect, showing that its not only the website that can be destroyed, but everything on that computer and potentially on the network.

Answer (score 1):

[How to mess up a pc](https://superuser.com/questions/275894/how-to-mess-up-a-pc-running-windows-7) has some nice ideas, though not all of them use Windows shell commands…

Answer (score 0):

```
mbrfix /drive 0 clean
```

That oughta do it :)

Works on most Windows versions (98 and upwards), as far as I know.

**Edit:** Though you can still boot into a recovery mode (using the cd) and do an `mbrfix /fix`. But just leave that away from your audience, shall we?

Of course like any other OS, there are all sorts of nasties you could use to bring it to its knees.

In older Windows versions, you could even do hardware damage. Nowadays you could have a little hardware detection tool combined with overwriting CMOS/flash memory (even GFX cards, as an example).

**Edit 2:** Nearly forgot, *you have to restart your PC for changes to take effect*. **:D**